# ng-pattern should not match supplied pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-ng-pattern

In `ng-pattern` we have the option of specifying that the field should match a specific pattern.

How can we specify that it should NOT match the specified pattern?

Example,

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/[*|\":<>[\]{}`()';@&$]/" />
```

Here, I DONT want the field to match the pattern. On the contrary, I want to show error if the pattern matches.

Comment: Do you want to use the same pattern? If yes, you'd need to create a custom validator. If not, you can use [`^(?:(?![*|\x22:<>\[\]{}\`()';@&$]).)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/nN8uK7/1), I think.

Comment: Looks like [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) I linked to does not have the other regex I showed in my comment. I think I should reopen the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check if a string does not have some substring, you can use a string-start-anchored lookahead:

```
/^(?!.*[*|\x22:<>[\]{}`()';@&$])/
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nN8uK7/3)

In AngularJS, the pattern does not have to match the entire string if a RegExp object is passed (the one with delimiters), so this regex suits the current purpose well (just check if a condition is true or false).

Note that the commonly used tempered greedy token solution `` ^(?:(?![*|\x22:<>\[\]{}`()';@&$]).)*$ `` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nN8uK7/1)) can be used, too, but it is less efficient since each position  in the input string is checked.

Also, it is convenient to use `\x22` to match a double quote in the `ng-pattern` value.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a negative lookaround (`(?!pattern)`) to negate your regex:

```
ng-pattern="/(?![*|\":<>[\]{}`()';@&$])/"
```

Comment: This will not work. Here is [a test](https://regex101.com/r/hK7zK7/1). The lookahead does not match anywhere in the string, it will match right after the current position. `/[*|\":<>[\]{}\`()';@&$]/` matches any of the symbols inside the character class, the opposite should make sure there is no such symbols in the entire string. A correct regex will be `/^(?!.*[*|\":<>[\]{}\`()';@&$])/`.